# Translating MatLab to R - array multiplication & complex conjugate transposition

Tags: r, matlab, translate, transpose

I'm trying to translate a code from MatLab into R, but I'm stuck on the following line:

```
SqO=U.* sqrt(D)*V'
```

I feel like I'm close:

```
SqO<-Conj(t(U%*%sqrt(D)*V))
```

...but the output still isn't matching up.  All the variables (Sq0, U, D, and V) are 20x20 matrices if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I'm no expert in R, but I do know a bit of Matlab.  In Matlab the sub-expression

```
U.* sqrt(D)
```

does an element-by-element multiplication of `U` and the square root of `D`.  That is, element `(i,j)` in `U` is multiplied by element `(i,j)` in `sqrt(D)`; so this is not the usual matrix multiplication.  Is that what your `U%*%sqrt(D)` does ?  `sqrt(D)` also operates on the individual elements, that is `sqrt(D)~=D^(1/2)*D^(1/2)`.

Then the Matlab code multiplies the result of the previous operation by the transpose of `V` (if `V` is a real array); again my R is too weak to know whether you've done this or an equivalent operation.

Comment: In R `%*%` is matrix multiplication, whereas `*` is element-by-element multiplication, so with your Matlab definitions (maybe) it ought to be `U*sqrt(D) %*% t(V)` , but you didn't give enough background about how the complex conjugate might enter in.

Comment: I didn't give any background on complex conjugates at all.

Comment: Right. Couldn't tell if that right-hand dot after 'U' had some mathematical meaning.

Comment: The `.` groups with the `*` to form a 2-character operator `.*` which means element-by-element multiplication. I wouldn't call it maths, I'd call it Matlab.

Comment: OK then .* in Matlab is the same as * in R. (Not what the OP wrote.)

Answer (score 1):

From what HighPerformanceMark wrote the translation should be:

```
SqO=U.* sqrt(D)*V'  # Matlab

SqO <- U* sqrt(D) %*% t(V)  # R
```